# Оптимизировать CSS код

Tags: css

Есть более 2000 тыс. строк такого кода:

```
body .post-12378{background-image: url("site.ru/images/gdijkn.gif")!important; background-repeat:repeat;}    
body .post-25371{background-image: url("site.ru/images/xcerui.gif")!important; background-repeat:repeat;}    
body .post-64403{background-image: url("site.ru/images/nmcdfw.gif")!important; background-repeat:repeat;}
```

Хочу оптимизировать CSS и применить **background-repeat:repeat;** один раз, чтобы не повторять к каждому коду.
Хочу заметить, что "**.post-**" это публикация-пост и мне приходится в ручную в CSS файле, **для нужных мне публикаций** прописывать **background**.
Как правильно будет выглядеть код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если:

1) классы по определению разные И

2) селектор вида `*[class^="post-"] {...}` применять нельзя (например, у вас помимо нужных элементов присутствуют такие, которые трогать нельзя) И

3) x-путь для этих элементов тоже разный (т.е., задать стиль для них и только для них путем указания чего-то наподобие `body .content .topic > .post-container > .post-header + div + div > div:first-child` нельзя),

тогда все, что вы можете сделать, это оптимизировать конструкции для каждого поста отдельно путем объединения записи свойств `background-image` и `background-repeat` в общее свойство `background`. Короче будет.

Answer (score 4):

Можно, если класс к каждой картинке добавлять не получается, но классы или ID имеют общий префикс, использовать селектор атрибутов:

```
body *[class^="post-"] {background-repeat:repeat;}
body *[ID^="post-"] {background-repeat:repeat;}
```

данная запись означает `применить стиль всем элементам, чей класс|ID НАЧИНАЕТСЯ c "post-"`.

Для специфичности (мало ли, у вас не только нужные блоки имеют класс с таким же префиксом) можно указать более специфичным селектором, типа

```
body .post-content div[class^="post-"] {background-repeat:repeat;}
```

Comment: @ИнквизиторЯ подкорректировал вопрос, а то что-то не те ответы, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

добавить класс типа `bg-repeat`

где

```
.bg-repeat {background-repeat:repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.post-12378 .post-25371 .post-64403 {background-repeat:repeat;}
```

Ты говоришь что ID разные,
ID указывается через "#" Пример: #post-64403

Через "." как у тебя указывается class Пример: .post-64403

Правильнее будет трем картинкам дать один класс например .post-777

```
<img class="post-777" src="картинка 1">
<img class="post-777" src="картинка 2">
<img class="post-777" src="картинка 3">
```

и код в css будет

`.post-777 {background-repeat:repeat;}`

Comment: @KeeplodВерно это классы (в реальности это публикации-посты) -> `.post-12378 .post-25371 .post-64403 {background-repeat:repeat;} `. А как с картинками? Имена-то разные у картинок.